# Testing VXML Applications in a Application Simulator

Tags: ivr, vxml, voicexml, avaya

I am looking for a solution to simulate vxml application in a desktop/web browser.

**Challenge** 
 i have few hundreds of unit test cases in every new vxml application development.
 it is not possible to always make a test call to test every single unit test cases i have. if i can test vxml application in a simulator it will be more easy to test it..

---

i am aware of that avaya Dialog designer/AAOD  have a feature to test application in their inbuild Application simulator which comes with AAOD/DD Eclipse package but this tool can run AAOD/DD projects in workspace alone. 
Please refer : Chapter 16 in [Avaya dev guide](http://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100088393)

AAOD's Tool looks like this 
[image: Application simulator tool in Avaya AAOD]

is it possible to customize to use this tool to simulate static VXML / Nuance NDF based VXML application ?

or any other tools available ?

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing of IVR applications is challenging and it is near impossible to hit ever possible path in the call flow for an application of any size.  I am not aware if you can customize Avaya's tool for your needs. But there is a product out there that may fit some of your requirements. It is [Voiyager by Syntellect](http://www.syntellect.com/pages/products/voiyager_eng.aspx).  It looks like they have a [free trial](http://voiyager.com/) now if you want to try it out.  I saw a demonstration of it at SpeechTEK a few years ago and it was pretty impressive.  The only reason I did not pursue it at the time is that it was pretty pricey.

Answer (score 0):

Avaya od/dd is a platform dependent tool(IDE) where you can create  (vxml+java), test and  debug application in the tool. But code which is created outside(Avaya OD/DD tool) the environment is not possible. Because code generated in avaya OD is java format, while executing in the voice browser it is converted into vxml for that u need to give webLM a license to avaya tool.You can use some ivr automation tools like hammer etc.But you need to pay for the software.

Answer (score 0):

VXML apps are just WARs. The only session information transferred between invocations of pages is the session id. We have used [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) to create apps.

What you can do it try and see if what you want to do can be done via the web browser, by going to `http://<server>/<Application/Start` there fill the boxes you require (most of the time just filling the ones marked ANI and DNIS will be enough).  If your call can be tested this way you can use the tools for web testing, without using Orchestration Designer.

If your app has a CTI/AES connector you may not be able to do this, because the web server tries to connect to AES upon submitting the first page.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above , there are things that cannot be unit tested .
Nuance NDF and SVF applications come with test pages where you can simulate the call flow ; similar tools exit for grammars .